# Any query returns TypeError: Failed to fetch in launchpad.graphql.com

Tags: graphql

If i create a new pad, the example Hello world from the repository will also give an error " TypeError: Failed to fetch". Also with other queries

[image: Here is a new page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://blog.apollographql.com/introducing-launchpad-the-graphql-server-demo-platform-cc4e7481fcba):

> We will be sunsetting Launchpad on December 15, 2018 now that our hosting platform, Auth0 Extend, is discontinuing their service. We decided to not invest time into moving to another service because more full-featured Apollo Server playgrounds currently exist. Please migrate all examples to either CodeSandbox or Glitch before December 15, 2018 so you don’t lose your work.